# Why that code doesn't setting null to value

Tags: c#, null

I can not understood why this code doesn't changing value from null(compiler even can't see that null instead of that Im reciving blank spots)

```
 public string? ClubName
        {
            get => _clubname;

            set
            {
                _clubname = value ?? "it";
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show how you are using that property? Show the value of the property before an assignment to it, show how you make the assignment. Then show us the value of the property after the assignment. Basically, let us step through your code

Comment: At no point is the setter for `ClubName` called in the code you posted, therefore it will have it's default value of null. If you write `Console.WriteLine(null)` it won't crash - it will just  be the same as `Console.WriteLine("")`

Comment: Because property setters are not called when you construct an object, but only when actually set the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setter uses the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator `??`, which substitutes "it" should `value` be null:

```
_clubname = value ?? "it";
```

So, you can never assign null to the property via the setter.

However, your property is backed by this private field:

```
_string clubname;
```

which the compiler initializes to null.

While you can never *set* `null`, the code in your screenshot never assigns a value, so the initial value remains.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question: *" why this code doesn't changing value from null"*  - note FROM null.

Comment: Ah. Because you never set a value, and `_clubname` is initialized to `null` by default.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: that make a sense, thanks so much! I overlooked that

Comment: @PoulBak: note that the question has been edited three times, taking it from nearly incomprehensible (the version this answer attempts to respond to) to merely confusing. I would not have guessed what the question was from the first version